# Flutter/Dart: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

```
I/flutter ( 9255): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9255): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Asset>>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 9255): _FutureBuilderState<List<Asset>>#734fc):
I/flutter ( 9255): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 9255): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 9255): Tried calling: length
```

-------Code Snippet ----------

```
Future<List<Asset>> getAssets() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Assets');
  print("created List Map from DB table Assets");
  //List<Asset> assets = List();
  List assets = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    assets.add(Asset());
  }
  print(assets.length);
  return assets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`rawQuery` is returning null.

You should your update code like this

```
List<Map> list = (await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Assets'))??[];
```

Comment: Future<List<Asset>> getAssets() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Assets');
    print(list[0]);
    List<Asset> assets = new List();
    //List assets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      assets.add(Asset());
      print('printing first asset row');
      print(list.length);
      print(assets[i].name);
      print('end print statements');
    }
    return assets;
  }

Comment: I/flutter (18346): {id: 1, name: Macys, username: mcuser, password: mcpasswor, url: macys.macys.com, notes: mcnotes, other: macysother}
I/flutter (18346): printing first asset row
I/flutter (18346): 3
I/flutter (18346): null
I/flutter (18346): end print statements
I/flutter (18346): printing first asset row
I/flutter (18346): 3
I/flutter (18346): null
I/flutter (18346): end print statements
I/flutter (18346): printing first asset row
I/flutter (18346): 3
I/flutter (18346): null
I/flutter (18346): end print statements
I/flutter (18346): 3

Comment: I think the statement assets.add(Asset()); should be like...assets.add(Asset(list[i]["name"],....). But it says too many positional arguments.